# Use Categories in Product URLs for ALL Urls - Magento

Tags: magento, url, categories

Systeam creates two URLs for one product:

http://www.website.com/shirt/white-collar-shirt

http://www.website.com/white-collar-shirt

I want only one URL with category in it....

In our store we not have many products - 30 or so. Is good idea to redirect with .htaccess ?

**Redirect 301 "/white-collar-shirt" website.co.uk//shirts/white-collar-shirt**

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Use of canonical Meta tag is recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bad idea to use .htaccess, because you'll have to make changes to it every time you change url key of product or add new one.

It's not a simple task, one of way to achieve it, is to create custom extension which will create url rewrites for products to url with category.

Another way if it's suitable for you is just set in configuration "Catalog > Search Engine Optimizations > Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products" and search engines will store url for that product as one for both url, but it will be url without category. It's easier to develop.

Comment: Products are not many ~30 and i think if there is no negative aspect of using .htaccess i will use it. I defenetly want my urls to have category string in it.